# Parsing Description tag in Rss Feed in iOS

Tags: ios, object, xml-parsing, rss, nsxmlparser

Am facing Problem in handling the description tag of RSS feed in iOS. 
I have given an example of RSS feed i have received.
I can not handle this description field without knowing the feed beforehand, so I can not make this parser generic.

my question is, can we make a generic RSS feed parser? If yes, then how? i have tried using NSScanner, but somehow i felt it was not much efficient. do we get a better alternative?

EDIT: 
i have already parsed the feed using NSXMLParser, i am getting the description field including the html tags, i want to get the original values extracted from there

```
<item>
    <title>End slavery in the U.S., world</title>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/23/opinion/myles-slavery/index.html</guid>
    <link>http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/Z13FFqE4z54/index.html</link>
    <description>The extraordinary new film "12 Years a Slave" immerses us in the reality of historical slavery at a deep level of complexity           and nuance. The film is an opportunity to honor all who were held in chattel slavery, treated like property, and subjected to levels of         violence, torture, and control that no human should ever endure.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
        &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img 
        src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a 
        href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:7Q72WNTAKBA"&gt;&lt;img 
        src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a 
        href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img 
        src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;     
        &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:qj6IDK7rITs"&gt;&lt;img 
        src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a 
        href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:gIN9vFwOqvQ"&gt;&lt;
        img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=Z13FFqE4z54:pYCgKZFqbkU:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/Z13FFqE4z54" height="1" width="1"/&gt;
    </description>

    <pubDate>Wed, 23 Oct 2013 09:05:27 EDT</pubDate>
    <feedburner:origLink>http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/23/opinion/myles-slavery/index.html</feedburner:origLink>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

RSS is just XML and is a well-defined format, so you can use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the feed and extract the information you need.

Comment: Obviously am doing using NSXMLParser, am getting the description field including the html tags, how to parse that part and retrieve data intact (without html tags) /

Comment: Actually, you said you were using `NSScanner`, not `NSXMLParser`. If you want to parse HTML, use a HTML parser such as [ObjectiveGumbo](https://github.com/programmingthomas/ObjectiveGumbo).

Comment: Do u mean, i will first get the description field out using NSXMLParser, (as I was doing) and then parse the description field separately using html parse? but this description as u can see is not totaly html as u see. please help me with some more detail

Comment: Yes, parse the RSS feed using NSXMLParser to extract the description, unescape the percents using `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on the `NSString`, and then parse that string using a HTML parser.

Comment: BTW, your original question was _can we make a generic RSS feed parser? If yes, then how?_ and I did answer that (_use NSXMLParser_).